# Node.js: get video and audio format information of an mp4 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, video, codec

I'm new to node.js.
I need to extract audio and video format (codec) information for a given video file.
I know how to do that in bash thanks to mplayer like this:

```
$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 myvideo.mp4 2>/dev/null | grep FORMAT

ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=H264
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=MP4A
```

I'm wondering if there's an npm module (library) that allows me to get same information. Alternatively I could launch the above command form node.js and read / parse stdout (I think there's plenty of examples around). However I'd rather use a node.js "native" solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, found it...

The module is fluent-ffmpeg (`npm install fluent-ffmpeg`), and here is how to get information:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.ffprobe('/path/to/my/video.mp4',function(err, metadata) {
  console.log(metadata);
});
```

or a more tailored example:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.ffprobe('/path/to/my/video.mp4',function(err, metadata) {
    var audioCodec = null;
    var videoCodec = null;
    metadata.streams.forEach(function(stream){
        if (stream.codec_type === "video")
            videoCodec = stream.codec_name;
        else if (stream.codec_type === "audio")
            audioCodec = stream.codec_name;
    });

    console.log("Video codec: %s\nAudio codec: %s", videoCodec, audioCodec);
});
```

Output:

```
Video codec: h264
Audio codec: aac
```

Comment: im assuming this would also work for other media files (`m2ts`, `mkv`, etc) considering ffmpeg itself is pretty comprehensive???

Comment: is this the repository for [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)??